# How to get totalCount and first document in a single MongoDB query result?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

There is a filter `myFilter` used to get some insights about the `xyz` collection.
Now I need to run three queries having the same step for filtering the documents

```
db.xyz.find(myFilter).sort(mySort1).limit(1) // get first item by sort #1
db.xyz.find(myFilter).sort(mySort2).limit(1) // get first item by sort #2
db.xyz.find(myFilter).count()                // get total count
```

**How to express the same intention in a single query or aggregation?**

Expected result is

```
{
  "item_1": {/* first doc by (myFilter & mySort1) *//},

  "item_2": {/* first doc by (myFilter & mySort2) *//},

  "totalCount": /* count of all by myFilter */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$facet` to run several pipelines on the same data at one query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$match: myFilter}
  {$facet: {
    item_1: [{sort1}],
    item_2: [{sort2}],
    totalCount: [{$group: {_id: null, count: {$sum:1}}}]
  }}
])
```